# Replace the default proxy on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Linux 2/Node.js) with lua-resty-auto-ssl for multi-tenant SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, multi-tenant, openresty

I would like to use [lua-resty-auto-ssl](https://github.com/auto-ssl/lua-resty-auto-ssl) as the default reverse proxy on Amazon Linux 2 instances managed by Elastic Beanstalk. I am hoping to terminate SSL for 100s of unique domains on this.

I have successfully used it on a separate EC2 instance, but when I try to use that as an AMI image for launching elastic beanstalk (using a network load balancer to forward 80/443) it **does** work but shows a red Degraded symbol, I think this is to do with platform hooks or competing nginx configs.

I wondered if there is a way to do it by [extending](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) the default platform rather than using an AMI. Or just a way to fix the health reporting of the AMI method.

Has anyone done anything like this? Or have any advice.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you have any luck on this?

Comment: @Chris Not with this method. I ended up using Caddy (https://caddyserver.com/) to handle the multi-tenancy SSL - a lot less painful and automatic. I then dockerized everything, so hosting it on aws or gcp was easier. Hope this helps.